# How to make custom placeholder images?

Tags: photoshop, placeholder

I know there are great services that offer placeholder images. I have used these. I wanted to make placeholder images for my office. Is there an easy way to generate specific image sizes rather then using a photo editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Try [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) or [dummyimage](http://dummyimage.com/)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite one is http://placekitten.com

You just need to set the src of your img with an url in this format `http://placekitten.com/{width}/{height}` eg `http://placekitten.com/g/200/300`

Every request will return a different image of a kitten

Ok placekitten images are not custom, the right answer is the previous one: https://dummyimage.com/ but those placeholders are not a pretty as kittens are